# Applications reporting “libc.so.6: cannot handle TLS data” after upgrading glibc

Tags: linux, upgrade, glibc

**Background Info:**

Linux OS: Stripped down, minimalistic and very customized (no apt-get, yum, etc)

Linux Kernel: 2.6.19.1

Current glibc version: 2.3.6

Target glibc version: 2.6.1

**Issue:**

Attempting to install an ipk package provided by 3rd party which has a dependency on a glibc version >= 2.6 (current version is 2.3.6)

The 3rd party provided a different ipk package to upgrade glibc to 2.6.1. After executing the install of the package, all other applications that depend upon glibc report "libc.so.6: cannot handle TLS data"

Is anyone familiar with upgrading glibc on a customized Linux OS without using any sort of package manager for support?

My understanding is that glibc should be backwards compatible and upgrading it shouldn't cause issues with applications that had previously been working. Is this assumption incorrect?

I can post more information as it is requested. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that glibc should be backwards compatible and upgrading it shouldn't cause issues with applications that had previously been working.

That is correct.

Your issue is most likely the result of mismatch between `ld-linux` and `libc.so.6` -- they *must* come from the same build, of bad things will happen (GLIBC actually consists of many libraries, and they *all* must match).

It's possible that your 3rd-party provided glibc package is mis-configured and replaced one, but not the other. Possibly it installed `libc.so.6` into `/usr/local/lib` instead of whatever location is appropriate for your OS.

So find all files that "belong" to GLIBC before the installation of 3rd-party update, and verify that every one of them is replaced by it.

It is also possible, though less likely, that the 3rd party package is simply broken, or configured without TLS support.

If you link an app against GLIBC with TLS support, then upgrade GLIBC to one configured without TLS support, the applications *will* break. That is expected and "normal" (configuring GLIBC without TLS support is simply not a good idea).

Comment: Yeah the issue was the `ld-linux.so.2` was still pointing to the old `ld` shared object library. Thanks again!